# How does 301 redirect works

Tags: url-rewriting, dns

In a typical DNS like GoDaddy and Yahoo, can a 301 redirect do this:

`http://mysite.com/abc` to `http://www.mysite.com/abc`

However it seems its not possible; Can the app in the `otherdomain` know the `subfolder`?

**Update:**

What I mean are those DNS redirects, specifically from naked domain to a www domain

**Update:**

I managed to forward the naked domain from `http://mysite.com` to `http://www.mysite.com/index.html` So can I get the requested subfolder through javascript in the index.html?

Or the re-direct loses the subfolder originally requested?

Comment: DNS cannot redirect to subfolder, DNS used only for "hostname" part of the url, so re-formulate your question in proper terms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HTTP 301 response is not handled by DNS. It's a response emitted by a web server to indicate to the browser that the requested resource has been moved permanently to a new location, and it includes a `Location:` header with the new URL

For example:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Location: http://www.example.org/index.asp
```

As you see, the location header can contain contain any valid URL, including a folder name.

Setting this up is server dependent, but Apache's mod_rewrite is certainly capable of rewriting URLs and including the requested folder name in the response.

Comment: I see, so when the DNS forwards to other domain, the app there, should check the header

Comment: Anyway, my only choice is URLRewriteFilter

Comment: DNS does **not** handle 301 redirects. The app at the new server won't necessarily be aware that the request has been redirected. The server at the new location will simply get the URL as it's set up in the redirect request.

Comment: So you mean, a forward like this will not work: `http://mysite.com/abc` to `http://www.mysite.com/abc`  where 'abc' is any hash string

Comment: No, that's not what I said. In the case of Apache's mod_rewrite it is possible to rewrite the domain, append the existing path and passing the result as a 301 response. What you suggest _will_ work if it's properly set up. Other servers have different mechanisms but should be able to do something similar.

Comment: I'm not really using Apache mod_rewrite. Anyway, I managed to forward the naked domain already to my www domain appending /index.html looks ok now, however the only problem I have is if I can get the original subfolder requested from the landing /index.html file

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a LAMP stack box, you can use .htaccess to redirect. You can redirect any page on site1 to any page on site2.

```
 Redirect 301 /old-page-name http://www.your-domain.com/new-page-name
```

note, this is not a DNS solution, but I think you might not be looking for a strictly DNS-related answer.